# construct a lebesgue integral function

Tags: measure-theory

Construct a Lebesgue integrable function $f$ with the property that for any interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (real line) and any $M >0$,

The measure $|{x \in I: |f(x)| > M}| > 0$

How would I go about constructing such a thing?

Comment: I don't know specifically, but I would try nesting characteristic functions of "fat" cantor sets. You should weight these characteristic functions with greater and greater weights to make things unbounded.

Comment: On second thought, the above is probably too complicated, but take your insights from a construction like the cantor set, or Thomae's function for instance.

Comment: See [this](http://www.austinmohr.com/work/hw/704/hw8.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}.$$

Then $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\Bbb{R}$ and $\{ g(x) > \tfrac{1}{2} \} = (-1, 1)$. Now let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb{Q}$ and define

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n} g\left( 4^{n} (x - r_n) \right). $$

Since each summand is non-negative, $f \geq 0$ and

$$ \int_{\Bbb{R}} f \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\Bbb{R}} 2^{n} g\left( 4^{n} (x - r_n) \right) \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{2^{n}} < \infty. $$

Now pick any $M > 0$ and any interval $I$. We may assume $I$ is open by taking the interior instead. Then there exists $n$ such that $2^{-n} M < \frac{1}{2}$ and $r_n \in I$. For this choice of $r_n$,

\begin{align*}
\{ f > M \} \cap I
&\supset \{ 2^{n} g\left( 4^{n} (x - r_n) \right) > M \} \cap I \\
&\supset \{ g\left( 4^{n} (x - r_n) \right) > \tfrac{1}{2} \} \cap I \\
&= \left( r_n - 4^{-n}, r_n + 4^{-n} \right) \cap I
\end{align*}

Since the set in the last line is non-empty and open, it has positive measure. Thus the same is true for $\{ f > M \} \cap I$ and the proof is complete.